# Use of "of you" vs "for you"

Tags: ambiguity

1. "It is so kind of you to help me"
2. "It is so kind for you to help me"

What's the difference between "of" and "for" there?
(I know no one using the second one, but I want to figure out the difference between them.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two constructions here.

> - (A) *It is advisable for you to take regular exercise. = For you to take regular* *exercise is advisable [an advisable thing to do].*
> - (A') *It is so kind for you to help me. = For you to help me is so kind [such a kind thing to do]*.

Note that "so kind for you to" scores almost 150 000 hits on Google, the first selection being largely relevant.

Note also that (B) *'It is so advisable of you to ...'* is not acceptable.

.............

> - (B') *It is so kind of you to help me.*

uses an of-phrase naming the referent after the adjective, thus '*kind of you*', cf '*[so] stupid of you', '[very] clever of you', 'thoughtful of him'*; these may be followed by a to-infinitival: '*so sensible of her to wear walking shoes', 'very prudent of the Government to order so many doses of vaccine'* etc.

Comment: thx for ur reply. in (A') "For you to help me" can be moved to the subject position (as a noun), and "so kind [such a kind thing to do]" act as a complement.
but in (B') "of you" is like an adverb/adjective directly modifying "kind/a kind thing to do" not a noun, am I understanding correctly?

Comment: Most would say 'noun group' or 'nominal'; terminologies differ. // Some would class 'of him' in 'typical/kind/thoughtful/ of him' as an _adjective complement_ as in 'afraid of spiders', but they are notionally very different strings. I'm only at the _'{so} typical/cruel/irresponsible ...  of X' is an idiom (or series of idioms)_ stage.

Comment: I (not sure) have also heard something like "for" has more hypothetical meaning, while "of" has more declarative meaning, could this be a possible difference existing?

Comment: 'Kind of you ...' certainly focuses more on the kindness of the _person_ (shown in doing the act) while 'kind for you to ...' focuses more on the 'kindness of the act' (note the strange way English transfers meaning; we call the act 'kind' though it's really only the person. This is taken to extremes in say 'a proud day'; 'a contemplative pipe'.)

Comment: ur replies really help me a lot :) thx !. some new ideas need to be absorbed but have to go to bed now.